# Customizing Icons at the top of the Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, icons, customizing

I'm maintaining a Facebook iFrame application, and my client is worried about the transition to Timeline. Basically, they want their home page to have a big icon next to 'Photos' that takes the user to the page hosting the iFrame. The tricky thing is that users can "pledge" within the app, and they want the link icon to look different depending on whether or not the user has pledged within the app. Is there any way to do this?

Assuming the answer is no, is there a way to add a second icon for the iFrame app so that I can customize one to look different? Or would I need to set up another page hosting the same iFrame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Fan Page Timeline, click the arrow on the half box to the right of photos, likes etc (assuming you haven't changed the order of the apps), hover over the icon you want to change and click on the pencil icon that shows up in the top right corner.  Then click "edit settings". Here you can change the tab image or give the tab a custom name.

alternatively you can enter the edit page settings, go to the apps section, edit the app, and you can change the icon from there.

in either case, you will need to be a page admin to complete the task.

**Update on 4/12**

Facebook just added the functionality for developers to set a default image.  [Here is the post in the Developer Blog.](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/11/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)